# I need to create a 'See more pictures' button in JS

Tags: javascript, image, search, giphy, giphy-api

I'm creating a gif website, which uses GIPHY API. In this website, I added a "Search bar", where you can type what kind of GIF you are looking for, and the websites returns 12 gifs from GIPHY.

This is my search function:

```
async function buscarGifs(valorDeInput,tipoRequest1,tipoRequest2,limit,num){
let urlSearch = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/${tipoRequest1}/${tipoRequest2}?api_key=${apiKey}&q=${valorDeInput}&limit=${limit}&offset=${num}&rating=g&lang=es`;
    let response = await fetch(urlSearch);
    return response.json();
}
```

What I was trying to do, is to create a 'see more' function: When you click the 'See more' button, the limit is modified, and the web shows you 12 more gifs (plus the first 12 gifs from the initial search).

This is how I call the 'buscarGifs' (gif search) function:

```
inputSearch.addEventListener("keyup", (event)=>{
if(event.keyCode === 13){ //Activa búsqueda con enter.
    printSearch(buscarGifs(inputSearch.value,"gifs","search",1,0),inputSearch.value);//Busca en API e imprime en DOM.
inputSearch.value = ""; //Vaciar casilla de búsqueda.
}
```

});

How would you do this?

Thx!

Comment: Load them into the DOM then, update that offset.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling the `buscarGifs` in the first place?

Comment: Of course, sorry for not adding it before. The function was added to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save current search query, offset and total results

```
let currentQuery, resultOffset, totalCount;

async function buscarGifs(valorDeInput, tipoRequest1, tipoRequest2, limit, num) {
  let urlSearch = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/${tipoRequest1}/${tipoRequest2}?api_key=${apiKey}&q=${valorDeInput}&limit=${limit}&offset=${num}&rating=g&lang=es`;
  let response = await fetch(urlSearch);
  let results = response.json();
  // update total results
  totalCount = results.pagination.total_count;
  // show hide more button
  if(resultOffset > totalCount){
    alert('no more results, remove more button');
  }
  return results;
}

inputSearch.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    currentQuery = inputSearch.value;
    // new search, reset to 0
    resultOffset = 0;
    printSearch(buscarGifs(currentQuery, "gifs", "search", 12, 0), currentQuery);
    inputSearch.value = "";
  }
})

// the more button
moreButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  resultOffset += 12
  printSearch(buscarGifs(currentQuery, "gifs", "search", 12, resultOffset), currentQuery);
})
```

Comment: Could you explain me this?:
totalCount = results.pagination.total_count;

Thx for your help!

Comment: `total_count` is the number of gifs returned by a query on Giphy's API

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like,

```
showMoreBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  printSearch(buscarGifs(inputSearch.value,"gifs","search",1,0),inputSearch.value);
  inputSearch.value = "";
}
```

Modify the `limit` and `num` params accordingly. I'm not sure why you used 1 and 0 to fetch the first twelve records in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, there used to be a '12' in there, I copied and pasted the code with that '1', but that's because I was trying something new. I will try with limit and num!